# TWebbrowser in Delphi displays error while compiling for OSX

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, twebbrowser

Good afternoon, I'm using **Delphi Tokyo 10.2.1** and trying to compile for **OSX Sierra** on my iMac. There is an error when I install and try to use a `TWebbrowser` component in my project, the error in question is as follows:

> First chance exception at $0001AC6C. Exception class EObjectiveC with message 'Method procedure webView(sender: WebView; didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame: WebFrame) of class TWebFrameLoadDelegate not found'. Process Project1 (1022)

If I remove the `TWebBrowser` component from the form it runs normally on imac. If I put it back to give this error! Is there any configuration in Delphi specific for this component?

Comment: Please don't post a capture of your entire screen. We don't need to see the IDE's toolbar, or any other part of the IDE, and we don't need to see your Taskbar. At the very least, you could capture just the exception dialog. At the very best, you could learn that hitting Ctrl+C with that exception dialog focused will copy the contents *as text* into the Windows Clipboard, where you can paste it *as text* into your post here or anywhere you'd like.

Comment: Have you tried the [tutorial for TWebBrowser](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_the_Web_Browser_Component_(iOS_and_Android))? Does it work for you?

Comment: Thats not a compile error is it?

Comment: Hello Ken, Hi David, thanks for the tip, I removed the image and left only the error message. I already used the tutorial yes, but in fact, if I create a new project and put a TWebBRowser in it no longer works. It seems like an error in the component itself.

Comment: If the tutorial works, then the component is fine. If the component was broken, then the tutorial wouldn't work either.

Comment: Tutorial not works, works only in Android and Windows, but not in OSX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone has the same problem, please know that the only way I was able to do it was to downgrade to **Delphi 10.1 Berlin**. Unfortunately the **Tokyo version** has some problem, even in the Android compilations. I reinstalled several times, including on other computers, but the problem persists at all. Anyway, it is now working correctly in the previous version.

Comment: Yes. Tokyo is massively flawed. I reported 3 errors on Embarcadero's QC only 30 minutes after I installed Delphi Tokyo.